# I trying to run a website but nothing works

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Reading not my code for web site. Early this site normal was working. Now it doesn't want to run. Nobody know why.

Using Visual Studio 2019.

Trying to run web site and don't understand what it wants from me. After debug everytime it shows me mistake: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAjE2.png)

On picture all on russian. Therefore I will translate:

> Source error:
> An unhandled exception while executing the current web request. Information about the origin and location of an exception can be obtained using the following exception stack trace.
>
> Build load trace
>
> === Pre-binding status information ===
>
> Log: DisplayName=Ext.Net.Utilities, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTokey=2c34ac34702a3c23 (Fully-specified)
>
> Log: Appbase=file...
>
> Log: Initial PrivatePath = C:...
>
> Calling assembly: Ext.Net, Version=2.3.1.41036, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2e12ce3d0176cd87.
>
> ===
>
> Log: this binding starts in the loading context default.
>
> Log: Application config file used:...
>
> Log: Master node configuration file in use:...
>
> Log: Computer configuration file from C:/...
>
> Log: link after applying policy: Ext.Net.Utilities, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c34ac34702a3c23.
>
> Log: trying to dowland a new one URL file:...
>
> Stack trace
>
> [ FileNotFoundExcep: Could not load file or assembly "Ext.Net.Utilities, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c34ac34702a3c23" or one of its dependencies. The specified file cannot be found.]
>
> Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule. Ajax RequstFilter (Objest sender, EventArgse) +0
>
> System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
>
> System.WebHttpApplicationStep.ExecuteStepImpl (IExecutionStep) +75
>
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93

I updated all packages NuGet. Utilities too. It doesn't help. Therefore my question is: How to resolve this?

Comment: @Filburt, thank you from right grammatical form my question. I'm rokkie here and don't know how all works on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this

1. Please try to clean your solution: Build -> Clean solution.
2. Try to remove any reference to this package: `Ext.Net.Utilities` and add it again.
3. Try to open your Visual Studio with administrator right's.

Comment: Sorry from grammatical form the my question. I'm rokkie here. Don't know all instrumens very well. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem @BroonCard, your here to find solutions. Did you manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: Now trying to make it. Using your advice @SuperPoney. Please, let me a bit time - my computer can't works with VS 2019 very fast =)

Comment: website working. It has problem with Oracle, but errors haven't now